# How do I find the first instance of a string in a text file using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to search text files for the first instance of string and return everything else in that first line, but my current program finds and returns the last line with the string.

Any idea what I need to do?

Thanks!

This is what my code looks like:

```
#Open search file as read only
with open(fullpath, 'r') as searchfile:

     #Clear variable names
     partname = partsize = None

     #Search file for strings, trim lines and save as variables
     for line in searchfile:

         if "PART FILE NAME" in line:
             x = line
             partname = x[18:-1]

         if "PART SIZE" in line:
             y = line
             partsize = y[18:-1]
     #Open csv file, write variables, close csv file
     storefile = open("C:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/blue pega3.csv", 'a')
     storefile.write("%s,%s,%s\n" %(partname, partsize, fullpath))
     storefile.close()
     #Close search file
     searchfile.close()         `
```

Comment: You're using the `with` statement so you shouldn't call `searchfile.close()`. In addition, it's called within the loop which is clearly wrong.

Comment: couldn't you just use regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to check if `partname` and `partsize` already have a value other than `None`:

```
partname = partsize = None

for line in searchfile:

    if partname and partsize:
        break

    if "PART FILE NAME" in line and partname is None:
        x = line
        partname = x[18:-1]

    if "PART SIZE" in line and partsize is None:
        y = line
        partsize = y[18:-1]
```

Comment: The `found` variables are unnecessary though.  If it's not `None`, it's found.

Comment: Fixed that, was to hasty there.

Answer (score 7):

Your code returns the last matches because you loop over the whole file, constantly overwriting `partname` and `partsize`.  You may only ovwerite them if they are not yet defined:

```
partname = partsize = None
with open(fullpath, 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if partname is None and "PART FILE NAME" in line:
            partname = line[18:-1]
        if partsize is None and "PART SIZE" in line:
            partsize = line[18:-1]
        if partname is not None and partsize is not None:
            break
```

The last `if` stops looping over the file if both lines are already found -- we don't need to continue searching then.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, sorry, but I think this is cool:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'search string')
try:
    with open('search file') as inf:
        # Read each line from inf, calling pattern.search(line).
        # ifilter() will keep reading until it gets a match object
        # instead of None. next() will either return the first
        # such match object, or raise StopIteration.
        match = next(itertools.ifilter(None,
                                       (pattern.search(line)
                                        for line in inf)))
except IOError as err:
    # ...
except StopIteration:
    # ...
```

The `try`/`except` obscures it a little, but the key point is that that single `next()` expression either delivers an `re.MatchObject` or raises `StopIteration`.

And of course, as with any `MatchObject`, the entire original line can be retrieved as `match.string`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
partname = partsize = None

#Search file for strings, trim lines and save as variables
for line in searchfile:

    if "PART FILE NAME" in line and partname = None:
         x = line
         partname = x[18:-1]

    if "PART SIZE" in line and partsize = None:
         y = line
         partsize = y[18:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If one day you would like to support more than 2 patterns then:

```
import csv

d = {} # name -> found part
patterns = ["PART FILE NAME", "PART SIZE", "part new"]
fieldnames = ["partname", "partsize", "partnew"]
names = dict(zip(patterns, fieldnames))

# find patterns in the file
with open(fullpath) as file:
    for line in file:
        if not patterns:
            break # nothing left to find

        for i in reversed(range(len(patterns))): # iterate in reverse
                                                 # to allow `del`
            if patterns[i] in line:
                d[names[patterns[i]]] = line[18:-1] # found
                del patterns[i] # search for the *first* instance only

# save found values
with open(outputpath, 'wb') as storefile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(storefile, fieldnames+['fullpath'])
    d['fullpath'] = fullpath
    writer.writerow(d)
```